# Odbc connection string results in login failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, odbc

Hi I have been trying all day to connect to my local sql-server database using ODBC but I seem to be missing something because every time I am trying to conenct I get this error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot
>   open database "Library.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot
>   open database "Library.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.

This is my source code:

```
 private string connectionString;

    public LibraryRepository()
    {
        connectionString = @"Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=Library.mdf;";
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> GetPersonDetails()
    {
        using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM Books" , conn))
            {
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new Book()
                        {
                            Id = (int) reader["Id"],
                            Name = (string)reader["Name"],
                            Author = (string)reader["Author"],
                            Description = (string)reader["Description"],
                            Price = (string)reader["Price"],
                            CategoryId = (string)reader["CategoryId"]
                        };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not really sure that the conenction string is ok when I look at the properties of the database at connection string I see this line :

> Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Library;Integrated Security=True

But if I add this line as the connection string I get this error:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

In order to veify if the data source is ok I logged into SSMS with (local) server name and it works I can also see my database there.

I have also set NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as the db_owner after reading a blog about this issue but still I get the error Cannot open database "Library.mdf" request by the login.

I am not really sure what to do next to solve this problem.Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection string is wrong. You should write the name of the database not the name of the file MDF that could contain many databases

```
connectionString = @"Driver={SQL Server};Server=local);" + 
                    "Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=??????;";
```

When you open your database with SSMS you should expand the Database node and look at how your database is called, then replace the question marks with that name

Comment: Thanks that was the problem

Comment: May I ask you why you want to connect to SqlServer using ODBC instead of the SqlClient?

Comment: @Steve I think you comment is better than your answer. It is about the _root_ problem.

Comment: @SonerGönül I have asked him because an IT manager forced me to use it with meaningless excuses and thus I have gone through hell's torments in order to adapt.

Comment: It's not my call to make I was told to use ODBC as the API I think they are nto sure they are going to use sql-server in the long rung but I am not really sure I just joined the project

Comment: @Steve That's sucks man! And people called him as _IT manager_ right? That's sad also. Some people just think only their opinion is right.

Comment: @SonerGönül But they have the wallet and so... In my country we say "tie the  donkey where the donkey wants"

Comment: @Steve In my country we say _If you wear a gold saddle to donkey, it is still a donkey_ `:)`